# How can the Unreal Development Kit be used with Android?

Tags: android, udk, unreal

I've read the [UDK will support Android development](http://3dg.me/gamedev/udk/udk-eventually-will-get-android-support), I checked the download page on the site and found nothing related to Android.

also read that Dungeon Defenders Android game was built with Unreal engine.

so is there a way to use the UDK with Android ?

Comment: Where have your read UDK will support Android development?

Comment: I got it from here http://3dg.me/gamedev/udk/udk-eventually-will-get-android-support

Comment: Why use UDK when UE4 - which supports Android - is free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that only the licensees have the access to android part of udk as the below page clearly mentioned about this

**`Android support is available to full UE3 source licensees. If you are developing a UDK title and wish to explore moving from UDK to UE3 in order to target additional platforms, please contact the sales team at Epic to discuss our competitive terms and licensing options.`**

http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/MobileHome.html

But if you want to confirm you can probably ask this on there development forums to the people who have there games out there.

[Here](http://forums.epicgames.com/forum.php) is the link to epics forum.

Answer (score 2):

We are currently dealing with the licensing for our upcoming game, and how it works is this: You can build for android, but only from the source code. And guess how much it costs to buy a source code license...

$50,000 per platform. D:

Kickstarter time I suppose!

you can distribute for iOS for as little as $99, and $2500 for a commercial license if I remember correctly. This was according to my recent phone conversation with their licensing team.

It's a shame, but I understand why they have to do it. I assume they had to sign some huge deals with Apple to even be allowed to make games in UDK for iOS, because Apple's terms changed when Epic Citadel Came out. While Fragmentation is of course an issue, I guarantee Apple has something to do with the lack of Android support as well. Just speculation, but Id be surprised if I'm completely off base.

Comment: Either you have no idea what you are talking about as your price per platform is incorrect or you do infact know what you are talking about and you are violating the terms of Epics NDA by disclosing the licensing cost. In which case you are libel to the damages set forth by epic's NDA and face a slew of other legal actions.

Comment: Or maybe they simply 'messed up' and told him stuff over the phone for which they usually have clients sign a NDA. Either way, my point is that you shouldn't be so quick to judge.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the UDK only support iOS for the moment and so there is no way to make it works on Android:

http://www.udk.com/mobile

As you say Dungeon Defenders was built with Unreal Engine and not with the UDK. According to Epic Game some problems such as performance and app size issues on Android prevent them to release an Android version of the UDK.

Comment: According to Epic...would you please add the link? I would like to read it. And I think android fragmentation is the major cause why Epic isn't working on the android version.

Comment: Yes fragmentation is a major problem for them. And this problem leads to performance issues. I have find this interview with Tim Sweeney (sorry but it's in french, use google translate) : http://www.frandroid.com/actualites-generales/66768_epic-games-se-decline-devant-android/ . And this one with Mark Rein : http://3dg.me/gamedev/udk/udk-eventually-will-get-android-support

Answer (score 1):

[UE4](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/what-is-unreal-engine-4) now supports Android AND has a new licensing program. Now its free, source code and everything, to develop games for any platform they support. They now charge a 5% fee on all gross revenue after the first $3000 per game per quarter. They currently support Android, iOS, web, Windows, Linux, and Mac OS.

Answer (score -1):

Use Unity 3D instead of UDK, they support iOS and Android. Mattering which technologies your game needs will define the licensing levels (shader support requires pro licensing). Building for each platform is an add on. iOS development has to be done on Mac OSX due to Apples EULA. Lot less expensive than UE3.

UE3 is a more powerful platform, but more expensive. Unity has better cross platform support and is more than capable for most indie games, UE3 fits better with big budget games.