# Is it possible to use plugins like Admob when creating a UDK game for Android or iOS?

Tags: udk, plugin

Is it possible to use plugins like Admob or Chartboost for iOS and Android when using UDK?

I am interested in an official or unofficial source where it's mentioned that the plugins are possible or not with UDK or if anyone have ever made plugins without using the original Unreal Engine Source?

Comment: See this related question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23218/how-can-the-unreal-development-kit-be-used-with-android (specifcally this page: http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/MobileHome.html from the answer) If you have to ask for a tutorial or where to get started on something, it's likely too broad to ask about here. This site is for specific answerable problems.

Comment: @Byte56 thanks for the link. However that's not related to my question at all. I am asking about the plugins i.e. using third party SDKs such as admob for UDK. I just wanted to know if it's possible or not. If it's possible, then I want to know the source where it's mentioned. That's it. I hope you got my point.